# CGI::unescape can't handle unescaping "wymiana+teflon%F3w"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, ruby-on-rails-4, escaping

I am working on data imported from legacy database into sqlite for development, legacy database has a lot of url encoded strings with Polish characters. I can get most of these strings readable by using

```
CGI::unescape_html( CGI::unescape "string" )
```

except for one case (that I noticed yet, there may be more as I didn't do any testing yet), the letter "[ó](http://unicode-table.com/en/00F3/)". For instance, using `unescapeHTML` on string "wymiana+teflon%F3w" throws an `invalid byte sequence` exception.

Question now is either my string is properly escaped, as other Polish characters are using sequences of "&#nnn;" like "b%26%23322%3Bad+zapisu+%2D+powinno+by%26%23263%3B+brak", which seems to follow standard for [numeric character referencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference). BTW, this string is properly unescaped into

> "bład zapisu - powinno być brak"

But, on the other hand, there are also strings with similar character encoding, e.g. "odpowietrzanie+weza%5C" which is properly handled by `CGI::unescapeHTML`. However, %5C represents a [backslash](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=U%2b005C) not a letter with code point lower than U+0256. Can it be the reason? I tried to research on this but haven't found any explanation. I also updated my Ruby to 2.1.0 as CGI::Util has changed in new version, but still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

`ó` is 0xF3 in ISO-8859-2 (and ISO-8859-1) but `'\xF3'` is **not** a valid UTF-8 string, that `ó` should be `%C3%B3` in the URL if you're expecting UTF-8. Someone somewhere probably used the deprecated [`escape` JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) to encode the string instead of modern [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent); you can see the difference with a simple test in your browser's JavaScript console:

```
> escape('ó')
  "%F3"
> encodeURIComponent('ó')
  "%C3%B3"
```

There's the `%F3` you're seeing and the `%C3%B3` that you want to see. One thing that should work is to fix the encoding by hand:

```
irb> CGI::unescape('wymiana+teflon%F3w').force_encoding('ISO-8859-2').encode('UTF-8')
 => "wymiana teflonów"
```

This assumes that you know what should be ISO-8859-1 and what should be UTF-8. You might have a mix of both ISO-8859-2 (or -1, -3, ..., Windows CP-1258, ...) in your data; unfortunately, there's no reliable way to tell the difference as the encodings overlap and there's no way to be sure what result makes sense without eye-balling it and knowing the various languages involved.

Probably the best you can do is:

1. Send everything through through your `CGI::unescape_html(CGI::unescape(...))` converter.
2. Wrap that in an exception handler to trap the inevitable problems.
3. Stash the problem strings off to the side somewhere.
4. Try the ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8 conversion on the strings from **(3)** and eye-ball them to see if they makes sense.
5. Repeat with other common encodings until there's nothing left that you care about.

Note that I'm using ISO-8859-2 instead of the more common ISO-8859-1 as Latin-2 is for Eastern European languages (such as Polish) whereas Latin-1 is for Western European languages. They overlap on `ó` but there is no `ł` in Latin-1. With tasks like this you usually try the encodings that are probably there first, then fall back on other common encodings, then fall back to whatever other encodings you can think of, and then fall back on hard liquor.

Good luck, modernizing legacy data is not the funnest job in the world.

Comment: You have a point with deprecated escaping in strings from my legacy database, but there is one thing I don't quite get: why result of `encodeURIComponent('ó')` is `"%C3%B3"`. This gives code point [Ã](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=U%2BC3). Shouldn't it be [ó](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=U%2BF3)?

Reference: [computer encoding of Polish alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_alphabet#Computer_encoding)

Comment: The two bytes in the UTF-8 representation of `ó` are 0xC3 and 0xB3. `CGI::unescape("%C3%B3")` should give you `ó` back if everything in your Ruby is in UTF-8 mode (and you really do want to be in UTF-8 front to back if at all possible).

Comment: You are right, [`%F3` is not a valid UTF-8 character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences). I didn't realized that UTF-8 is such a mess!

Comment: It isn't that much of a mess, it is just a variable length encoding to maintain compatibility with 7bit ASCII. And it certainly much better than the insane mess of encodings (Latin-N, Windows CPX, JIS, EUC, SJIS, Big-5, ...) that we had to deal with before UTF-8 was common.

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen another way to solve my problem, simply substituting all occurrences of `'%F3'` with `'%26%23xF3%3B'` before  unescaping. BTW, capital letter [Ó](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=U%2bD3) also needs similar substitution. The actual code I used:

```
  def unescape_ó(s)
   s = s.gsub(/%D3|%F3/, {'%D3' =>'%26%23xD3%3B', '%F3' => '%26%23xF3%3B'})
  end
```

With this approach I don't have to handle `invalid byte sequence` exception as properly escaped string is used in `CGI::unescapeHTML`

Comment: The problem here is that you could get a percent-encoded `ć`, `ł`, `é`, ... in your data and a simple `gsub` won't fix those.

Comment: I don't need to handle such case as all remaining Polish characters are properly escaped, `CGI::unescapeHTML( CGI::unescape unescape_ó("string") )` will handle all.